# Как разделить код в Symfony 6

Tags: yii2, symfony

Перехожу с фреймворка Yii2 на Symfony 6.2
В Yii есть модули. Это практически мини приложение со своими контроллерами, компонентами и другими классами. В Symfony есть бандлы, но судя по описанию, они задумывались как структура composer пакета.

Можно ли сделать бандл в исходном коде проекта с собственным пространством имен, но не выносить его в composer пакет?
Идея в том, чтобы писать часть приложения в бандле, но выносить его в отдельный репозиторий только в случае необходимости его использования в других проектах.

Есть ли другие аналоги модулей как в Yii, только в Symfony?

Comment: Посмотри https://github.com/vudaltsov/symfony-modular-skeleton  . может на мысли натолкнёт  .... и ещё статья https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/symfony-1-1-en/chapter-4/creating-a-module-skeleton